# matlab function variable amount inputs

Tags: matlab, function

Maybe this is very simple question for you guys, but I'm trying to write a function in MATLAB that works when having just 2 inputs or more. I have been looking for a solution, but couldn't find exactly what I wanted. It is like this

```
function myfunction(x1,y1,x2,y2)

    plot(x1,y1) %// user just puts x1,y1

    %// or

    plot(x1,y1,x2,y2) %// user puts x1,y1,x2,y2

end
```

I want the function to work, when the user just puts `x1,y1` as the input, but I also want it to work when the user puts `x1,y1,x2,y2` and plot a figure.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [`varargin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) to accept multiple inputs or use [`exist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) to check for additional inputs. I personally prefer `exist` because then the input arguments can maintain useful names.

**`varargin` Example**

For your scenario, use of `varargin` really simplifies your function. Using `varargin{:}` simply passes *all* input arguments to `plot`.

```
function myfunction(varargin)
    plot(varargin{:})
end
```

**`exist` Example**

Here, `exist` will yield `false` if `x2` or `y2` are not supplied to the function.

```
function myfunction(x1, y1, x2, y2)

    if exist('x2', 'var') && exist('y2', 'var')
        plot(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    else
        plot(x1, y1)
    end
end
```

Comment: You can also use `nargin` for simple cases.